# Как в языке С возвести 4 в степень i без pow &

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Стоит математическая задача с запретом использовать pow

Comment: А Вы попробуйте сделать это руками, на листке бумаги. Возьмите произвольное i, и посчитайте 4^i, а потом свои действия перенесите в код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запросто. Ибо что такое 4<sup>i</sup>? Это 2<sup>2i</sup>

Значит, надо просто выполнить сдвиг...

```
1 << 2*i
```

Comment: Тут уж главное чтоб `i` было не слишком большим и положительным.

Comment: @EOF Будет слишком большим - и цикл не спасет :)

Comment: Надеюсь, ТС не попробует в следующем задании таким способом возвести в степень ну, скажем, 7..... или 3....

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов А вам не кажется, что **4** тут неспроста? И вопрос не в универсальном методе?

Comment: @Harry Вполне вероятно. И для этой конкретной задачи Ваш метод не только уместен, но и очень хорош. Просто мне кажется, было бы неплохо в ответе указать его ограничения, чтобы ТС (или другой прочитавший) не попытался его применить там, где это не подходит.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Гм, мне казалось, что мое "*Ибо что такое 4^i? Это 2^2i*" уже объясняет, что сдвиг - только для степеней 2...

Comment: @Harry Хочется надеяться :) Увы, я вполне могу представить себе человека, который подумает что-то типа "Хм.. 9 - это три в квадрате, тогда 9^i можно посчитать так: 1<<3*i..."

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить 2 варианта.

сделать в цикле с умножением либо со сдвигом.

int pow = 1;
for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++)
{
pow *= 4;
}

либо

int pow = 1;
pow = pow<<2*i;